# Why isnt my textUpdate function displaying text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why my `textUpdated()` function isn't working ?

I want to display text under my container(`<div id = 'textUpdate'>`) but nothing displays.

If youd like to check out the full code: https://repl.it/@securethebags/theBeatles-quiz

To run it:
https://thebeatles-quiz.securethebags.repl.co/

I have tried changing the logic behind my `if-else-if` statement but that didn't work. I also checked to make sure all my var names were correct :

```
function selectAnswer(e){  //called when an answer button is pressed
    clearStatusClass(document.body)
    const selectedButton = e.target;
    const correct = selectedButton.dataset.correct
    Array.from(answerButtonsElement.children).forEach(button =>{
        setStatusClass(button, button.dataset.correct) // change 
        background for each button if answer is correct/wrong
    })
    if(shuffledQuestions.length > currentQuestionIndex + 1){
        nextButton.classList.remove('hide')
    }
    else{
        startButton.innerText = "Restart"
        startButton.classList.remove('hide')
    }
    updateScore(correct);
    textUpdatd() 
}

function textUpdatd(){
    textUpdate.classList.remove('hide')
    if(scoreboard.right == questions.length)
        textUpdate.innerText = "WOW you got them all right! Groovy!"
    else if(scoreboard.wrong == questions.length)
        textUpdate.innerText = "WOW you got them all wrong! Gnarly!"
    else if(scoreboard.right > scoreboard.wrong)
        textUpdate.innerText = "Not bad! - You must know your stuff!"
    else if(scoreboard.wrong > scoreboard.right )
        textUpdate.innerText = "Not doing too hot! Better luck next time!"
    else if(scoreboard.wrong == scoreboard.right && scoreboard.right != 0 || scoreboard.wrong != 0)
        textUpdate.innerText = "You are currently tied with right and wrong answers!"
    else
        textUpdate.innerText = "Something must of went wrong!" 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return from your function.  Add a return statement to your function.

I see you have forgotten a semi colon `;` after you have called your function.

Also, you can inspect your page by hitting <kbd>F12</kbd> and opening the console tab to see what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Hello any one reading this.

My issue was that it was 230 am and I needed to remove the class 'hide' but was doing so in the wrong place. To fix it I removed the class of hide upon the user pressing the 'next' button